# ¿Cómo poner separador de doble comillas para evitar el separador de comas?

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedure, csv

Tengo una aplicación que exporta datos a partir de un procedimiento almacenado.

Esto me funciona bien pero el contenido del archivo .csv (archivo final) solo que en los datos vienen con comas y al abrirlo en excel este lo separa en columnas.

De qué forma puedo agregar doble comillas o algo mas para evitar esto?

Muchas gracias de ante mano.

Aqui esta mi código:

```
conn.Open();

SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(outCsvFile))
{
    file.WriteLine(reader.GetName(0) + ',' + reader.GetName(1) + ',' + reader.GetName(2)
    + ',' + reader.GetName(3) + ',' + reader.GetName(4) + ',' + reader.GetName(5));

    while (reader.Read())
        file.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString() + ',' + reader[1].ToString() + ',' + reader[2].ToString() + ',' + reader[3].ToString()
        + ',' + reader[4].ToString() + ',' + reader[5].ToString());
}
conn.Close();
```

Comment: ¿Algún ejemplo de como deseas la salida? ¿Algún otro ejemplo de cómo es tu salida actual?

Comment: Hola, lo que pasa esque la concatenacion con las comas separa bien el archivo, pero en varios de las columnas hay ya comas existentes, deseo separarlas siempre con comas pero que en cada columna este rodeada de doble comillas para poder evitar que el archivo se quiebre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrias ayudarte con el `string.Join()` y definir el `\"` para que agregue la comillas dobles abarcando el dato:

```
SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(outCsvFile))
{
    List<string> items = new List<string>();
    for(int i=0; i<=5; i++)
    {
        items.Add(reader.GetName(i));
    }
    file.WriteLine("\"" + string.Join("\",\"", items) + "\"");


    while (reader.Read())
    {
        items = new List<string>();
        for(int i=0; i<=5; i++)
        {
            items.Add(reader[i].ToString());
        }
        file.WriteLine("\"" + string.Join("\",\"", items) + "\"");
    }

}
conn.Close();
```

Recomendaria tambien evalues usar `FileHelper` o `CsvHelper`

[Read/Write CSV files using FileHelpers](https://naveedahmad.co.uk/2015/03/15/c-readwrite-csv-files-using-filehelpers/)

[CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)

son excelentes opciones para crear csv

Comment: Hola, hice lo que me sugieres pero ahora el archivo me lo pone todo en una sola linea, ya no me lo pone tabulado como antes.

Comment: el \" al principio y al final de que parte?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Espero no te moleste, he agregado algo que le faltaba al código, sólo ponia comillas entre las celdas, pero no al principio y final.

Comment: ok si justo estaba por editar para agregar esas comillas que faltaban

Comment: Esta perfecto! excelente sugerencia. Me funciona todo como yo queria que funcionara. Muchas gracas!